# import hashlib - cxFreeze

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze, hashlib

I wrote a programm which uses cxFreeze but if I try to compile it with cxFreeze I get the error:

> Missing modules:
>   ? _md5 imported from hashlib
>   ? _sha1 imported from hashlib
>   ? _sha256 imported from hashlib
>   ? _sha512 imported from hashlib

It seems to me, that cxFreeze is not compatible with the hashlib module because the error is easy to reproduce. You just have to import hashlib and try to compile it.

Example:
cx_test.py:

```
import hashlib
```

setup.py (for cxFreeze):

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
buildOptions = dict(
        compressed = True,
        path = sys.path)
setup(
    name = "Hashlibtest",
    options =   dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    includes = ["hashlib"],       
    executables = [Executable("cx_test.py")]
    )
```

Any ideas how I can fix the problem?

I work with Python3.2 under Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score -1):

It's not a problem - if you look at the source code for hashdist, it uses different modules depending on whether or not Python was compiled with OpenSSL. Other modules might import one thing on Windows and another on Linux, or one for Python 2 and another for Python 3.

In all these cases, cx_Freeze sees all the `import x` statements, and looks for all of the modules. If it can't find one, it gives you that message. But it will still produce a program, and that will normally still work, unless there are other problems.

I've seen those messages for hashlib before, and the resulting program has worked just fine.

Comment: I read this before but in my case the program doesn't work. I also compiled it under windows and got no issues with the program. Seems to be a linux-only problem...?